# gnuplot: How to get %c zero space for numbers 1-999?

Tags: gnuplot, prefix

To my understanding there should be one empty space between numbers and units.

However, in gnuplot the prefix `%c` (see  `help format specifiers`) for numbers from 1-999 apparently seems to be `' '` instead of `''`.
So, in the example plot below neither the xtic labels nor the ytic labels are all correct.
Either you have some tic labels with *zero* space or with *two* spaces, but not all with *one*. It's a detail and maybe some people won't even notice, but if possible I would prefer to do it the correct way.

Quite some time ago I placed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2266/), but no response so far.
Is there maybe an immediate workaround?

**Code:**

```
### wrong prefix for %c 1-999
reset session

set size ratio -1
set logscale xy

set format x "%.0s%cΩ"    # no  space
set format y "%.0s %cΩ"   # one space
set xrange [1e-3:1e12]
set grid x, y
plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Based on the answer of @maij pointing to the source code, here is a gnuplot attempt to "fix" this, which should be easily transferred to C.

**Code:**

```
### gnuplot "fix" for prefix for %c 1-999

prefix(power) = "yzafpnum kMGTPEZY"[(power+24)/3+1 : (power+24)/3 + sgn(abs(power))]

do for [power=-24:24:3] {
    print sprintf("% 3g  '%s'", power, prefix(power))
}
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
-24  'y'
-21  'z'
-18  'a'
-15  'f'
-12  'p'
 -9  'n'
 -6  'u'
 -3  'm'
  0  ''   # zero length
  3  'k'
  6  'M'
  9  'G'
 12  'T'
 15  'P'
 18  'E'
 21  'Z'
 24  'Y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug.

This is the workaround I came up it. With this, there is always one space between the number and the units.

You can tell gnuplot where to set each tick mark individually and what each label should be, with `set xtics add`. The function `gprintf` can format a number using gnuplot specifiers.

Since we already know what value each tick should have, it's easy to set them with a loop.

```
# Function to choose the right label format.
f(x) = (x < 1000 && x >= 1) ? gprintf("%.0f Ω", x) : gprintf("%.0s %cΩ", x)

# Loop to set each tick mark and label.
do for [i=-2:12:2] {
    set xtics add (f(10**i) 10**i)
    set ytics add (f(10**i) 10**i)
}

set size ratio -1
set logscale xy
set xrange [1e-3:1e12]
set grid x, y

plot x
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Yes, this fixes it although it is not nice to set the tics manually if you have autoscale and autoticlabels in gnuplot. Since I asked for an immediate workaround I will accept this answer. Nevertheless, I hope that it will be fixed in the source code as @maij suggested.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix the source code:**

Currently I have only source code of the Debian Stretch gnuplot version 5.0.5, linenumbers etc. might be outdated.

The problem is in the function `gprintf` in `util.c` around line 868:

```
power = (power + 24) / 3;
snprintf(dest, remaining_space, temp, "yzafpnum kMGTPEZY"[power]);
```

Here we see the following:

- the letters in `yzafpnum kMGTPEZY` are the scientific prefixes.
- From 1 - 999, `power = (0 + 24) / 3 = 8`
- and `yzafpnum kMGTPEZY"[8]` is the additional space

I am not a C expert, but as a first attempt, I changed this to

```
power = (power + 24) / 3;
if (power != 8) { 
   snprintf(dest, remaining_space, temp, "yzafpnum kMGTPEZY"[power]);
} else { 
   snprintf(dest, remaining_space, "%s", "");
}
```

(The `gprintf` function expects at least a terminating null character to be printed, most probably there are simpler solutions.)

**A workaround without recompiling:**

What about setting the tic labels manually? But I think you came up with this idea before and don't like it.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see. This explains why it is `' '` and not `''`, because of the simplicity of the function. I agree, this should be _very_ easy to fix. And I hope this will be done in the "official" source code and not by everybody individually. I don't know C at all, so I add to my question a gnuplot attempt, although it will not fix the issue. But I'm sure this can easily be translated to C.